# Are "caminar" and "andar" interchangeable?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Today, as I was expanding my vocabulary, I've come across the verb "andar". I looked it up and I noticed that it has several meanings. One is "to walk". I thought of "caminar".

Can "caminar" and "andar" be used interchangeably, or is there any rule which determines when to use "andar"?

Comment: My first thought was that interchanging wouldn’t work in this old song lyric, “caminando en este mundo ando yo” https://genius.com/Flex-sin-tu-amor-1078993-lyrics

Answer (score 7):

**Caminar**

The word *caminar* is used mostly for the physical act of walking and not much else.

> Yo camino a mi trabajo.
>
> Ella camina a la escuela.

There are some exceptions, of course, but probably not worth mentioning here.

**Andar**

Andar can also mean *to walk* and in that sense is nearly interchangeable with *caminar*, although *caminar* is probably used more commonly.

> Yo ando a mi trabajo.
>
> Ella anda a la escuela.

However, as shown [here](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/andar) and [here](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=andar), *andar* also has many other meanings. I'll just list a few:

> Yo ando en bicicleta.
>
> ¿Porqué anda con una cara triste?
>
> El coche no anda bien, porque tiene una llanta desinflada.

You can find many more examples in the links I provided.

**To summarize,** ***caminar*** **is mostly used to mean "to walk".** ***Andar,*** **although it can also mean "to walk", is used more for other meanings such as "to go", "to travel", "to function", "to act", and more.**

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, in Spanish spoken in the central pacific part of Mexico and in Los Angeles, caminar is used to express "to walk:, andar is used to express "go around walking" or "to walk around".